# Laravel 4 - Return average score from within model?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I'd like to return the average score for game reviews in my database. I am building my site with Laravel 4.

TABLE STRUCTURE:

```
GAMES (id, title, etc)
REVIEWS (game_id, user_id, score, etc)
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function singleGame($id)
{
    $game = Game::find($id);

    if ($game)
    {
        return View::make('game')->with('game', $game);
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

My thought is to hopefully return the average score for a game through $game->average in my view, but I've been unable to produce the desired result through fiddling with my Game model.

GAME MODEL:

```
public function scores()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Review')->avg('score');
}
```

I've tried a number of methods available to the query builder, but I'm still learning the ropes when it comes to Laravel/PHP, so I'm kinda stuck. Perhaps I should be approaching the problem differently?

Thanks.

Comment: I was answering you on IRC.. rage. Here is what I said. I will help in IRC, not in here. http://paste.laravel.com/XuF

Comment: Haha. Sorry about that, my internet connection dropped out. And yes, we use Bigpond here in the office!

Comment: Also, what's wrong with if (something) return ; else return? How do you do it?

Comment: @Robbo i don't see why you don't want to answer here. if you are in the comunity, it means you are willing to help while getting too. but saying, _I will help you in x place and not in y place_ creates a negative impression and is also unhelpful for future readers of this question who may have been facing the same issue. in that case, i would want to get a clue of what's the answer is.... __NOT SOME__ chats of two guys. isn't it?

Comment: Firstly the if (something) return else return is because the else isn't needed and makes that code ugly.

Comment: And didn't mean to press enter... secondly to itachi who just decides to be a douche. I wasn't sure about what you were trying to do so couldn't provide an answer on here. Talking in real time I can get what information I need very easily. If I knew the answer I would have answered.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are two alternatives for you:

**Readability (two queries)**

```
$game = Game::find(1);
$game->average = $game->reviews()->avg('score');
```

Note that this assumes that you have got a reviews function for your relationship in your game model.

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Game');
}
```

This alternative is using the [avg aggregate](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#aggregates) function. The aggregate functions provided by the [QueryBuilder](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Query.Builder.html) returns only the aggregate scalar.

**Performance (one query)**

If you really want to do this in one query. Here is one alternative:

```
$game = Game::select('games.*', DB::raw('avg(reviews.score) AS average'))
    ->join('reviews', 'reviews.game_id', '=', 'game.id')
    ->groupBy('reviews.game_id')
    ->where('game.id', '=', 1)
    ->first();
```

Comment: Fantastic. I will use your first suggestion. Is it easy to reorder my games by average score?

Comment: Just as a side note: At least in Laravel 4, `avg()` is not a method of collections, unlike `sum()`, `max()` or `min()` etc. For collections, in Laravel 4, I do `sum()/count()` for `avg()` approach.